# Golang default workspace(GOPATH) does not exist

Tags: eclipse, go

I am new to Go and installed latest windows version of Go:

[image]

and it set the default workspace.

[image]

That GOPATH-C:\Users\avnee\go does not exist in my machine. Even when I set it to different path, it does not work. I want to run simple "hello world" program in eclipse.

wanted to set variables. Ideally I expect to see below variables as gocode, guru and godef in my machine and then I can set it. Referred the official url: "https://go.dev/doc/gopath_code#GOPATH" but does not help.

Eclipse snapshot below:
[image]

Any help is appreciated.

I am also getting error on opening go project as

[image]

Comment: The Go plug-ins you have installed doesn't correctly support Java 10 and newer. If there are newer versions of it, update.

Comment: I am currently on Java 8. Do you want me to update java 8 to latest version, redo goclipse installation?

Comment: Eclipse has not been runnable on Java 8 for years, so you're either using a pretty old version, or you're not using the version of Java you think.